# JMeter: Difference between using Number of Threads and Constant Throughput Timer

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, stress-testing

What's the difference between **Number of Threads** and the **Constant Throughput Timer**?
Before I heard of the **Constant Throughput Timer**, I thought that if I wanted to simulate 21 requests per minute , the following configuration was enough :

[image]

but now that I found [this post](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer), I'm not so sure.

This is my new configuration now that I make use of the **Constant Throughput Timer** :

[image]

[image]

1. Does the **Constant Throughput Timer** override the parameters specify in Thread Group (Number of threads,Ramp-up period, etc) ?
2. Why even making use of the **Constant Throughput Timer** I sometimes get a number of requests higher than the value specify in the **Target Throughput** (21 in the above image)
3. If a indicate a value of 21 in the **Target Throughput**, isn't this constant supposed to guarantee a maximum value of 21 requests? If so why do I sometimes get more requests than indicated.

All your comments and ideas will be appreciated.
[image]

P.S. I'm also using a Runtime controller.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

No, it regulates the number of requests going to & response received from the server per minute.

As stated in the Jmeter user guide "the throughput value should not be changed too often during a test - it will take a while for the new value to take effect."

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer

The issue you have shown above will always happen in the first minute of the test run.

hope this will help.

Comment: So it is completely normal too have an extra request the first time we run our test plan? That is, if I specify **x** as the **Target Throughput**, I will always get **x+1** requests in the first executions of the test plan? Is it mentioned somewhere in the documentation?

Comment: I'm having this same issue. Is there any explanation why this happens the first time we run a test plan? I don't think I've seen anything mentioned in the documentation

Comment: "the throughput value should not be changed too often during a test - it will take a while for the new value to take effect." 

this above line is mentioned in the documentation, so no matter what you do, during the first run it will always be X+1.

Comment: I am trying to understand the difference between 1) 100 virtual users and Constant Throuput timer as 600 requests per minute and 2) 200 virtual users and Constant Throuput timer as 600 requests per minute

Comment: I too have this question, as eddy asked #1 Does the Constant Throughput Timer override the parameters specify in Thread Group (Number of threads,Ramp-up period, etc) ?